# array of forward declared struct in another struct

Tags: c, struct, forward-declaration

I am trying to forward declare a struct A and define a struct B that contains an array of A.
I am getting error stating 'incomplete type not allowed'

This is what I have:

```
struct A;

struct B
{
// something 
struct A x[10]; // This where I get the error incomplete type not allowed
};

struct A
{
// something
};
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a work around you can declare a pointer to struct A as this

```
struct B
{
// something 
struct A * x;
};
```

This is because if you have a line like

```
struct B b;
```

the `b` will have a member `x[10]`. If you did not fully declare struct A, struct B doesn't know how to allocate 10 struct A elements. In the workaround, if you only declare a pointer, struct B doesn't need to know how to allocate struct A but only need to know how to allocate one pointer.

Answer (score 1):

An "incomplete type" ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/200xfxh6.aspx)) is a type whose details the compiler doesn't know at a given point in the translation unit. In the declaration of members of `struct B`, the compiler doesn't know the size of the type (`sizeof (struct A)`) and therefore doesn't know how much space to leave for it. Another reason for not allowing `struct` members of incomplete type is that if they could, this would have allowed "circular composition" where `struct A` contains members of type `struct B` and vice versa. I don't see how the size of the result of such a circular composition could even be defined.

Workarounds:

- To include `struct A` by value in `struct B`, complete the type first. Move the declaration of members of `struct A` above that of `struct B`.
- A `struct` is allowed to include pointers to incomplete types as members. In `struct B`, include an array of pointers (`struct A *x[10];`) Then populate it with objects of type `struct A` allocated separately, possibly through some factory that calls `malloc(sizeof(struct A))`, fills out its members, and returns the pointer. You're then responsible for freeing the memory used by these instances.